# Admob Not Showing After Publishing to Playstore

Tags: java, android, admob, adsense

I have a problem.
I have Android App project that using Admob to show Ads.
The Admob Ads is showing when I install it from APK file, but It's not showing when Install in Playstore. Is there any setting i missed?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It usually takes time for the Play-store APK to show ads. Could you please share your code?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Taseer Ahmad. Here is my code.

//This is My Activity Code
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.banner_app_id));
AdView mAdview = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: //This is my XML code
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/id"/>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Sorry this is my first question, I dont understand yet to answer and put the code properly.